# Problem on normed space.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, topological-vector-spaces

**Let $X$ be a normed space, $Y$ a dense subspace of $X$ and $Z$ a closed finite-codimensional subspace of $X$. Is $Z\cap Y $dense in $Z$ ?**

I have no idea how to solve this problem. I am using this website for the first time, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose first that the codimension of $Z$ is $1$.  Then $Z=\ker\phi$ for some nonzero $\phi\in X^*$.  There is some $y\in Y$ such that $\phi(y)\neq0$.  Define $P:X\to X$ by 
$$Px=x-\frac{\phi(x)}{\phi(y)}y.$$
Then $P$ is linear and bounded, $PX=Z$, and $PY\subset Y\cap Z$.  If now $z\in Z$, there is a sequence $\{y_n\}$ in $Y$ converging to $x$.  Thus $\{Py_n\}$ is a sequence in $Y\cap Z$ converging to $Pz=z$.

In general, if $Z$ has codimension $n$, then $Z=\bigcap_k\ker\phi_k$ for some nonzero $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_n\in X^*$, and we can find $y_1,\ldots, y_n\in Y$ such that $\phi_k(y_k)\neq0$.  Then define $P:X\to X$ by
$$Px=x-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\phi_k(x)}{\phi_k(y_k)}y_k.$$

Comment: Note:  This proof is not mine.  I asked a friend at school about this, and they found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is dense in $Z$.
draw a picture with one disk and a secant line, you will find the secret.
the line is a finite dimension space, there are many points belong to $Y$
around the line but not in the line, because the line-finite dimension space is nowhere dense(suppose $X$ is infinite dimensional)